# ¿Como recuperar formulario en netbeans 8.2?

Tags: netbeans

Resulta que estaba trabajando en un proyecto de Java en el IDE netbeans 8.2, mi pc es un poco mala.... y por momentos al estarla forzando demasiado o mucho tiempo encendida se congela y hay que apagarla, entonces le di a guardar mientras estaba trabajando en un formulario y yo que doy click y la pc que se congela... no me altere pues no es algo que me extrañe lo de congelarse entonces la apague, ahora... cuando la reinicie despues de un rato y abri netbeans.... el formulario en que estaba trabajando ESTABA TOTALMENTE VACIO EL SORUCE y la parte de la interfaz grafica dice "The form file does not contains valid XML. The form cannot be opened" y era un formulario que tenia alrededor de unas... 2000 lineas programadas restandole todo lo que agrega netbeans.... porfavor alguien sabe como recuperarlo?

Comment: Revisa tu proyecto carpeta por carpeta, dentro de `NetBeansProjects`, si es que usaste el directorio por defecto de NetBeans. Si lo encuentras, felicidades y si no, piensa en corregir el grave problema de tu PC. Si no es tan vieja quizá necesite un formateo e instalación nueva. Si es muy antigua, quizá debes ir pensando en renovarla, si es posible.

Comment: A mi también me pasó lo mismo pero perdí los últimos 5 días de código, en mis 25 años de programas jamás me había pasado esto tan extraño, justo iba a hacer commit de estos cambios, y eso que tengo Subversion, ojalá alguien aclare este misterio que no tiene ningún sentido ya que son días de haber guardado el código, como se supone que se regresa a una version anterior así de la nada?. Amigo tu también tienes subversion? tal vez ese fue el problema. saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Pues al final si pude arreglar en cierto modo el problema. Cuando abrí el formulario sale que el xml no lo encuentra y en fin, error, entonces al darle ok a ese mensaje me mandó al source, o sea el código del formulario, donde no había absolutamente nada, solamente una única linea como si se hubieran dado cientos o miles de veces a la tecla espaciadora, entonces nos encontramos con tres botones que siempre vemos pero el tercero de "History" jamas lo usamos casi, entonces me fui a ese esperando encontrar algo que pudiera devolverme las esperanzas, y efectivamente.... ESTABA EL CÓDIGO del guardado anterior!! no la interfaz gráfica, PERO ESTABA EL CÓDIGO que era lo mas importante, por suerte tenia copias de seguridad de hace unos cinco dias, no tenian el trabajo actual pero si tenían la interfaz grafica asi que tuve que renombrar todo y luego ir poniendo en los eventos de cada control los códigos que le correspondian, total que al cabo de unas cinco horas ya estaba como antes de que se arruinara.

No es una solución definitiva, pero el hecho de recuperar al menos el código del formulario en que estés trabajando eso ya anima bastante porque al final la interfaz son solo controles puestos y varios clicks en propiedades.

Comment: Revisar [answer].